# Function recursion relation over symmetric group

Tags: symmetric-groups, determinants

Hi!

Let P be a permutation in the symmetric group S<sub>N</sub> and let π=π<sub>j, j+1</sub> be a transposition of elements j and j+1 of the permutation. Let A(P) be a function in dependence of the permutation P. Pπ is the permutation P with elements j and j+1 switched. I need to get an explicit expression of A(P) for the recursion relation:

$$\frac{A(P\pi)}{A(P)} = - \exp(-i(k_{p_j}- k_{p_{j+1}}))$$

k<sub>j</sub> are numbers, and $p_j$ is the j-th element of the permutation.

I hope someone can give me a hint or advice to solve this.

Tobias

Comment: You might simplify it by considering the function B(P) = i*log(A(P).  I assume i*i + 1 = 0 here.  Also, this may be "too localized" to be appropriate for Math Overflow.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.06.23

Comment: Hm ok, it's a problem I came up on physics but thought it might fit more on mathoverflow. This comes up on solving a many-body model with Bethe-ansatz. I might ask this question on "physics overflow" then. 

Comment: This isn't as "localized" as you might think Gerhard.  But I would want to encourage Tobias to edit his equation to provide a couple examples (unless it's a standard homework problem in a first year grad course, in which case you shouldn't have asked it in the first place).

Comment: Another quick note on clarity: When you say "P$\pi$ is P with j and j+1 switched", it sounds like you're possibly describing P conjugated by $\pi$, rather than P$\pi$.  Of course that's not what you wrote, and that wouldn't lead to a sensible recursion, I don't think, but still...